# How to post an actual website online using socket.io and node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, socket.io

I'm new to the whole website developing area (and frankly programming all around), but I've created this small website-based videogame, when I run it locally it works just fine (localhost) but I've tried posting it online (via github's page service) and I get `socket.io.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`. I'm not sure if there's something else I need to install or do before actually posting the website online or if there's just something wrong with my code. Any tips are much aprpeciated.
My code:
server-side javascript:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);
//code stuff

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/start.html');
});




io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
  players_joined = players_joined + 1
  console.log(socket.id);
//more code stuff

  socket.on('disconnect', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user disconnected')
    players_joined = players_joined - 1
  });
  
}); 


server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});


app.use(express.static('public'));
```

client side javascript

```
let socket = io()

//code
```

Note: I also get Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined on the let socket = io() line in the client-side javascript

I haven't tried much since I'm not sure what the error means, I know the websocket logic works because I've tested the code on localhost. I assume i need to enter the page's url at some point in my code but I can't figure out where or if there's something else other than websockets that I need to install to make the program work

Comment: Github pages does not run your serverside javascript code, it serves only static html pages. You'll need to find a hosting service that actually provides a nodejs runtime - or a bare-bones (virtual) server where you install and run it yourself

Comment: @Bergi understood, I see lambda (AWS) runs node.js should I transfer the server sided javascript there? Is there any video you'd recommend regarding the issue?

Comment: Also, please use the proper name for the language.  Your code is in "Javascript".  "Java" is a completely different programming language and "Java" is not a nickname for "Javascript".